# C IPv6 TCP Multicast

Tags: c, ipv6, multicast

Just a generic question, is it possible to have a tcp instead of UDP ipv6 multicast client/server setup?  If so can you provide a link to any examples, I've been searching everywhere and seem to be getting differing responses.

my assumption is no... but I want to be sure.

Comment: No. TCP is unicast. There is also 'anycast'.

Comment: Similar topic:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4823739/175849